# Trailing return types in member functions

Tags: c++11, trailing-return-type

I am trying to learn the concept of trailing return types and the possibility of its usage in member function overloading using tag dispatch. A toy implementation I have written is as follows:

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    // Tags
    namespace Params
    {
            struct t_param1{};
            struct t_param2{};
    };

    // Selectors to choose the appropriate member functions
    template<typename t_detail>
    struct Select;

    template<>
    struct Select<Params::t_param1> {using choice = Params::t_param1;};

    template<>
    struct Select<Params::t_param2> {using choice = Params::t_param2;};

    template<typename t_object>
    class Tester
    {
            private:
                    using t_uint32 = uint32_t;
                    using t_string = string;

            public:
                    template<typename t_detail, typename t_entity>
                    void assign(t_entity&& entity);

                    // There is a compilation problem here
                    template<typename t_detail>
                    auto access() -> decltype(access(typename Select<t_detail>::choice()));

            private:
                    t_uint32 m_param1;
                    t_string m_param2;

            private:
                    template<typename t_entity>
                    void assign(const Params::t_param1&, t_entity&& entity);

                    template<typename t_entity>
                    void assign(const Params::t_param2&, t_entity&& entity);

                    auto access(const Params::t_param1&) -> decltype(m_param1);
                    auto access(const Params::t_param2&) -> decltype(m_param2);
    };

    // Calls the appropriate assign function based on type t_detail
    template<typename t_object>
    template<typename t_detail, typename t_entity>
    void
    Tester<t_object>::assign(t_entity&& entity)
    {
            assign(typename Select<t_detail>::choice(), entity);
    }

    template<typename t_object>
    template<typename t_entity>
    void
    Tester<t_object>::assign(const Params::t_param1&, t_entity&& entity)
    {
            m_param1 = entity;
            cout << "Assigned m_param2 with " << entity << endl;
    }

    template<typename t_object>
    template<typename t_entity>
    void
    Tester<t_object>::assign(const Params::t_param2&, t_entity&& entity)
    {
            m_param2 = entity;
            cout << "Assigned m_param2 with " << entity << endl;
    }

    // Should call the appropriate access function used on type t_detail
    template<typename t_object>
    template<typename t_detail>
    auto
    Tester<t_object>::access()
            -> decltype(access(typename Select<t_detail>::choice()))
    {
            return(access(typename Select<t_detail>::choice()));
    }

    template<typename t_object>
    auto
    Tester<t_object>::access(const Params::t_param1&)
            -> decltype(m_param1)
    {
            return(m_param1);
    }

    template<typename t_object>
    auto
    Tester<t_object>::access(const Params::t_param2&)
            -> decltype(m_param2)
    {
            return(m_param2);
    }

    int main() {
            auto tester = Tester<string>();
            tester.assign<Params::t_param1>(32);
            tester.assign<Params::t_param2>("something");

            auto param1 = tester.access<Params::t_param1>();
            auto param2 = tester.access<Params::t_param2>();

            cout << "Access: param1 = " << param1 << endl;
            cout << "Access: param2 = " << param2 << endl;

            return 0;
    }
```

This is just a toy example as is not useful code. I know there is mistake in how I have declared the public access function. However, I am trying to figure out what it is and also understand why the compiler throws the following error.

```
no matching function for call to 'Tester<std::basic_string<char> >::access()'
  auto param1 = tester.access<Params::t_param1>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `access` function you're trying to call still doesn't exist at the time you're trying to call it. ([Live version.](http://ideone.com/OhgI7b))

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace Params {
    struct t_param1 {};
    struct t_param2 {};
};

template <class t_detail>
struct Select;
template <>
struct Select<Params::t_param1> {
    using type = Params::t_param1;
};
template <>
struct Select<Params::t_param2> {
    using type = Params::t_param2;
};

template <class t_object>
class Tester {
    using t_uint32 = uint32_t;
    using t_string = std::string;
    t_uint32 m_param1;
    t_string m_param2;
    auto access(const Params::t_param1 &) -> decltype(m_param1);
    auto access(const Params::t_param2 &) -> decltype(m_param2);
    template <class t_entity>
    void assign(const Params::t_param1 &, t_entity &&entity);
    template <class t_entity>
    void assign(const Params::t_param2 &, t_entity &&entity);
public:
    template <class t_detail, class t_entity>
    void assign(t_entity&& entity);
    template <class t_detail>
    auto access() -> decltype(access(typename Select<t_detail>::type()));
};

template <class t_object>
template <class t_detail, class t_entity>
void Tester<t_object>::assign(t_entity &&entity) {
    assign(typename Select<t_detail>::type(), entity);
}

template <class t_object>
template <class t_entity>
void Tester<t_object>::assign(const Params::t_param1 &, t_entity &&entity) {
    m_param1 = entity;
    std::cout << "Assigned m_param2 with " << entity << std::endl;
}

template <class t_object>
template <class t_entity>
void Tester<t_object>::assign(const Params::t_param2 &, t_entity &&entity) {
    m_param2 = entity;
    std::cout << "Assigned m_param2 with " << entity << std::endl;
}

template <class t_object>
template <class t_detail>
auto Tester<t_object>::access()
    -> decltype(access(typename Select<t_detail>::type())) {
    return access(typename Select<t_detail>::type());
}

template <class t_object>
auto Tester<t_object>::access(const Params::t_param1 &)
    -> decltype(m_param1) {
    return m_param1;
}

template <class t_object>
auto Tester<t_object>::access(const Params::t_param2 &)
    -> decltype(m_param2) {
    return m_param2;
}

int main() {
    auto tester = Tester<std::string>();
    tester.assign<Params::t_param1>(32);
    tester.assign<Params::t_param2>("something");

    auto param1 = tester.access<Params::t_param1>();
    auto param2 = tester.access<Params::t_param2>();

    std::cout << "Access: param1 = " << param1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Access: param2 = " << param2 << std::endl;
}
```

> Could you stop writing in C++ as if it was Java, please? :)

Comment: Thank you very much Polkovnikov. I now understand that the order of calls is important when trailing return types are used.

Comment: Out of curiosity, you have change the keyword 'typename' to 'class' in many a place in the code. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: @vixiv Yep, `template <template <...> class A>` currently works only with `class` keyword. So it's currently better to use `class` for consistency. Also it's easier to see keyword `typename` that is used in template metafunctor calls now.

Comment: Thank you for the above clarifications.